# How to correctly combine options -R and --remote-tab in gVIM

Tags: vim

How to correctly combine options `-R` and `--remote-tab` in gVIM?

The following command opens two tabs with files `-R` and `file.txt`:

```
gvim.exe --remote-tab -R file.txt
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
gvim.exe -R --remote-tab file.txt
```

Everything that comes after `--remote-tab` is interpreted as filenames.